# Automatic build errors resolving

Tags: compiling, gcc, cross-compilation, configure

Again I am compiling from scratch a big OSS project for custom **embedded** environment and receive a lot of errors like:

```
warning: libXXX, needed by YYY, not found 
fatal error: XXX: No such file or directory.
undefined reference to XX
```

etc

I have no tools like dpkg-buildpackage in my build environment. Buildroot doesn't helps too.

I manually search for missing packages with utilities: `nm`, `apt-file search` and configure compilation.

Question:

Are there utility, which parses errors, searches for missing components and proposes obvious solutions?

For example, like following code, which proposes to add missing library to `LDFLAGS`:

```
perl -ne '/.*warning: lib(.*?)\..*, needed by .*, not found .*/ && print "export LDFLAGS+=\" -l$1\"\n";' < config.log
```

Comment: I think is a near dupe of an earlier question. The package management system might be able to help you, if it exists. What OS/distribution, please?

Comment: Embedded Linux from scratch.

Comment: Does it have a package manager, and if so, which one?

Comment: No.
It is custom embedded Linux environment.